# How can I find the data point in my PCA plot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made this PCA plot in ggplot2. Is there a way to find which of my data produced the data point with the red arrow? I'd like R to tell me what species is associated with this data point (I have names associated with each dot, which represents a species PC score)

Code:

```
df_out <- as.data.frame(PPCA.scores)
theme <-
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black"),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "line")
  )
percentage <- round(PPCA$Eval / sum(PPCA$Eval) * 100, 2)
percentage <- diag(as.matrix(percentage))
percentage <- paste0(names(percentage), " (", percentage, "%)")

p<-ggplot(df_out,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2)) 
p<-p+geom_point(size=3) + theme + xlab(percentage[1]) + ylab(percentage[2])
p
```

[image: PCA plot]

Comment: what code did you use the create the plot? because you can usually pass in another variable (e.g. species) as a colour or fill argument and the plot will show you what species each point belongs to

Comment: p<-ggplot(df_out,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2))
p<-p+geom_point(size=3)+theme + xlab(percentage[1]) + ylab(percentage[2])
p

Answer (score 5):

The package `factoextra` provides a way to carry out PCA with labelling individual data points

```r
set.seed(123)

# pca object
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)

# plot
factoextra::fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, repel = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

For more detailed documentation, see-
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily using just ggplot, assuming all you want to do is be able to quickly identify (visually) which species a point belongs to:

```
library(ggplot2)

irispca <- prcomp(iris[c(1:4)], scale.=T)

df$PC1 <- irispca$x[,1]
df$PC2 <- irispca$x[,2]
df$species <- iris$Species

ggplot(df, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=species)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

If you want to label with the species name, you could do:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) + geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label=species))
```

[image]

Or index of each point:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=species)) + geom_point() 
    + geom_text(aes(label=rownames(df)))
```

[image]

If you want to just label a single point, assuming you know the row and index of that point, you can do something like this (you can also just manually set the position/label):

```
# get the row corresponding to that specific point
point <- df[110,]

# if you want the point that is at the max of PC1, for example, you could instead use this:
point <- df[df$PC1 == max(df$PC1),]

ggplot(df, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) + geom_point()
    + annotate("text", label=point$species, x=point$PC1, y=point$PC2)
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the best way to go about plotting if one had 100s of species though?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want the plot to show. the above can show all 100, but will get a bit cramped. or do you just want to single out 1 point?

Comment: If you know the row/index of that specific point you want, you can just annotate that single element. See my edit

Comment: what if one didn't know the row/index?

Comment: In that case how would you tell R what point you want to label? like, what would R use as reference? the XY coordinate? In your example you used an arrow, but what criteria did you use to determine thats the point you want?

Comment: I want to find the species associated with the points at the min and max of PC axes. So the data point in the upper right would probably be the max for PC1.

Comment: so you can just subset your dataframe using min/max as conditions. For example, if you want the point that is at the max value of PC1, you could use `point <- df[df$PC1 == max(df$PC1),]`, then use annotate like in the last example. replace min with max, or PC1 with PC2 to get different combinations for whichever point you want

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ggbiplot` too, this one is from the documentation, with the *wine* dataset, where the *ground-truth* (*wine.class*) is available.

```
# install ggbiplot package, if not already installed
#library(devtools)
#install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")

library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
head(wine)
#  Alcohol MalicAcid  Ash AlcAsh  Mg Phenols Flav NonFlavPhenols Proa Color  Hue   OD Proline
#1   14.23      1.71 2.43   15.6 127    2.80 3.06           0.28 2.29  5.64 1.04 3.92    1065
#2   13.20      1.78 2.14   11.2 100    2.65 2.76           0.26 1.28  4.38 1.05 3.40    1050
#3   13.16      2.36 2.67   18.6 101    2.80 3.24           0.30 2.81  5.68 1.03 3.17    1185
#4   14.37      1.95 2.50   16.8 113    3.85 3.49           0.24 2.18  7.80 0.86 3.45    1480
#5   13.24      2.59 2.87   21.0 118    2.80 2.69           0.39 1.82  4.32 1.04 2.93     735
#6   14.20      1.76 2.45   15.2 112    3.27 3.39           0.34 1.97  6.75 1.05 2.85    1450

wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
print(ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = wine.class, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE))
```

[image]